# Bash - filter files in the folder

Tags: bash

So I have this problem: I have a folder in my Ubuntu which contains log files. The naming pattern of all files is as following:

d**1**.exert.**de**-access.log-**2016-06-28**

There are plenty of files. I highlighted with bold what part of the name can vary. There are always two files for specific date and domain (.de, .co.uk, .dk etc.), one of which is prefixed with d1 ane the other one with d2. I need to concat d1 and d2 files for each date and domain, for example:

```
1) d1.exert.de_access.log_2016-06-28
2) d1.exert.dk_access.log_2016-06-24
3) d1.exert.dk_access.log_2016-06-25
4) d2.exert.de_access.log_2016-06-28
5) d2.exert.dk_access.log_2016-06-24
6) d2.exert.dk_access.log_2016-06-25
```

I need to pair and concat files: 1) and 4), 2) and 5), 3) and 6) because they have the same domain and date, but different prefixes.

So I need to go through all files in the folder and find these d1/d2 pairs for every date and domain. Then I have to concat these pairs. I need to write a script that will automatically find these pairs. I thought about some sort of double loop (e. g. the outer one searches date, and the inner one searches for domain) but I don't have idea how to achieve it. Or maybe there is some easier solution?

Comment: A side note : `zcat` cannot be used for non gzip format,

Answer (score 0):

You can use *sort* command to sort them, then *cat* command to merge them.

Example:

```
# sort all files
ls *novono* | sort | sort -t '_' -k 3 > files
# get all dates
DATES=`cat files | sed 's/...www.novonordiskpro..._access.log_//' | uniq`
# merge files
for DATE in $DATES; do cat `grep $DATE files` > merge-$DATE; done
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your script line by line, please? How does it merge by date AND by domain? Let's say, I want to merge files from 2016-06-25 but only for .de domain. Won't you script merge all files from this date, also with different domain than .de?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the files are always paired:

```
 ls -1 | sort -t\. -k 2 -k 1 | xargs -L2 your_command
```

This will sort the files to ensure that the matching pairs follow each other and then call `your_command` with exactly two arguments.

Answer (score 0):

script.sh "folderpath"

```
#! /bin/bash

cd $1;
for i in `ls | awk -F"." '{sz=$2"."$3"."$4"."$5; print sz}' | sort | uniq`
do
    file_d1=d1"."$i;
    file_d2=d2"."$i;

    #echo $file_d1;
    #echo $file_d2;

    cat $file_d1 >> $i;
    cat $file_d2 >> $i;

done
```

Final concatenated files will be store at "folderpath" with following filenames:

```
www.novonordiskpro.<domain>_access.log_<date>
Example:
www.novonordiskpro.dk_access.log_2016-06-24
www.novonordiskpro.dk_access.log_2016-06-25
```